# How to split the column values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I am trying to train a ML model to predict book genre based on movie titles, but since each movie has mixed Genre the accuracy of my model is very less because it is not able to match the Genres properly.
I want to keep only the first genre that appears in 'Genre' column. How can I achieve it?
I tried

```
df['Genre'].split(',')[0]
```

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: if you do df[<column_name>] it will return a series so split won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Top_Genre'] = df['Genre'].str.split(pat = ",", expand=True)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Genre'] = [ data.split(',')[0] for data in df['Genre']]
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to do this provided Genre column has a string of Genres

```
def get_first_genre(x):
    return x.Genre.split(',')[0]

df["firstGenre"] = df.apply(get_first_genre, axis=1)
```